# How to handle a device with a joystick button?

Tags: c++, winapi, sdl

I have audio devices which include a joystick button.(plantronics starset headset)

In my application I should use multiple of this devices at the same time,I should get the information about whick one is clicked to direct the voices. I can not couple audio device with the joystick button because SDL library gets the same oemname for all of different devices. We can see the different ids in control panel, same id in game controllers window at the following pictures ( [Controller Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jC9R.png) ,  [Game Controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpr6H.png) ) .

How can I couple the devices(already same device but I can not get true name of joystick button), how can I get the real name of a joystick(usb) device in C++ programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with tracking the devices in regedit. My device is a audio-microphone-joystick device and also HID. So windows identifies each devices seperately. In regedit the same device records of sound, audio and joystick has the same parentID value. So I can match the joystick devices to the sound device with that parentID value.

SDL enumerates the devices in the same order with Directx. Using directx we can get that "parentID" value from "DIPROP_GUIANDPATH" property of directx device. So I get the parentID value of the device from Directx and match that device name to the same device with same index with SDL. So I can get name of the joystick whose button is pushed. I can give detail information if one demands.